# Cannot get rid of "Please select Android SDK" error when trying to profile APK file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

I have found plenty of similar issues like this but none of the solutions worked for me or profiling environments specifically. What I have tried:

- Installed the correct version under `File -> Settings -> Android SDK`,
- Set the correct version under `Open Module Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies`,
- setting either default SDK or SDK from app bundle in the profile configuration,
- tried building with and applying different APK versions.

Really running out of ideas here. Would be glad if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building a sample app in the same way as the APK you are trying to profile, and then profile the sample APK? If you can reproduce the issue, may I suggest opening an issue (within Android Studio, click Help > Submit Feedback) and including the reproducing steps and sample APK?

Answer (score 0):

Was solved by updating the Java SDK, the message is just heavily misleading.